# Delphi ActionMainMenuBar MRU

Tags: delphi, mru, taction

I am trying to add an MRU list to an ActionMainMenuBar but cannot figure out how to do this, could someone please either point me to a MRU component that works with ActionMainMenuBar or perhaps tell me how to do this.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about which part of the task you're having trouble with?

Comment: i don't get how to add dynamicly items to the menu. could you help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a sample project doing this in Delphi 7 and up.

..\Samples\Delphi\VCL\ActionBands\MRU

See this post in SO [how-can-i-create-a-most-recently-used-file-list-in-delphi-2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605664/how-can-i-create-a-most-recently-used-file-list-in-delphi-2009)